# Linq query from navigation properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq, entity-framework

In entity framework i have two table (two entities): People and Role with one to many relationship. In the People tables i have a navigation property to Role:

```
public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
```

I'm able to retrieve all people that have role as 'barman':

```
var listPeople = (from p in SiContext.People
                  where p.Roles.Any(x => x.Name == "barman")
                  select p).ToList();
```

How can i retrieve all people with the related role? I want the person name and surname and the role name (that is in the role table)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This?

```
var peoples = SiContext.People.Include("Roles");
```

or

```
var peoples = SiContext.People.Include(p => p.Roles);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select from multiple entities:

```
from p in SiContext.People
from r in p.Roles
select new { Name = p.Name, ..., Role = r.Name }
```